# Swift equivalent of this class

Tags: swift, class

I'm trying to implement some basic UIGestureRecongnizer controls from [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50398/opengl-es-transformations-gestures) tutorial. I am having some trouble understanding and translating this class into Swift 3

```
interface Transformations : NSObject

- (id)initWithDepth:(float)z Scale:(float)s Translation:(GLKVector2)t Rotation:(GLKVector3)r;
- (void)start;
- (void)scale:(float)s;
- (void)translate:(GLKVector2)t withMultiplier:(float)m;
- (void)rotate:(GLKVector3)r withMultiplier:(float)m;
- (GLKMatrix4)getModelViewMatrix;

@end
```

(ps: the methods with the GLK prefix are from Apples GLKit framework)

```
class Transformations: NSObject {
    init(Scale: Float, Translation: GLKVector2, Rotation: GLKVector3) {
        func scale(s: Float) {
        }
        func translate(t: GLKVector2, withMultiplier: Float) {
        }
        func rotate(r: GLKVector3, withMultiplier: Float) {
        }

    }
}
```

So far, how is this?

Here is the .m file I am trying to translate into Swift 3.

```
#import "Transformations.h"

@interface Transformations ()
{
    // 1
    // Depth
    float   _depth;
}

@end

@implementation Transformations

- (id)initWithDepth:(float)z Scale:(float)s Translation:(GLKVector2)t     Rotation:(GLKVector3)r
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        // 2
        // Depth
        _depth = z;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
}

- (void)scale:(float)s
{
}

- (void)translate:(GLKVector2)t withMultiplier:(float)m
{
}

- (void)rotate:(GLKVector3)r withMultiplier:(float)m
{
}

- (GLKMatrix4)getModelViewMatrix
{
    // 3
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelViewMatrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, -_depth);

    return modelViewMatrix;
}

@end
```

Comment: What trouble are you having with it? What have you managed so far? You haven’t actually asked a question yet.

Comment: I will edit in my current attempt

Comment: void means that the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also, you haven't included the z parameter in your init

Comment: see! it just proves how little I know about obj-c code, I have been going about this all wrong. I honestly have no idea what im doing.

Comment: Your first problem is that in ObjectiveC all those are methods. Not variables. You should take a look at some OvjectiveC basics first. You won’t need a lot I think. `- (void)scale:(float)s` is equivalent to `func scale(s: Double)`

Comment: @E.Huckabee not knowing objective C is perfectly reasonable. There are many many resources that go into the basics of Objective C. You won’t need much. Just the very basics of how functions and properties work etc...

Comment: This is only the interface; in Objective C every class has two files, the header file (.h) and the implementation (.m); in this file there are only methods declarations, you should see the .m file that contains the implementation and translate to Swift.

Comment: I edited my question with my updated code.

Comment: You shouldn't include the scale, translate and rotate methods inside your init method.

Comment: just stop commenting what I should and shouldn't do here, and actually provide an answer. I'm completely lost on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should translate the .m file. Something like this:

```
class Transformations: NSObject {

    var _depth: Float

    init(z: Float, scale s: Float, translation t: GLKVector2, rotation r: GLKVector3) {
        self._depth = z
    }

    func start() {

    }

    func scale(s: Float) {

    }

    func translate(t: GLKVector2, withMultiplier m: Float) {

    }

    func rotate(r: GLKVector3, withMultiplier m: Float) {

    }

    func getModelViewMatrix() -> GLKMatrix4 {
        var modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelViewMatrix, 0, 0, -_depth)
        return modelViewMatrix
    }

}
```

Comment: No real need to inherit from NSObject unless that functionality is absolutely necessary. Most times it is not.

Comment: Thanks so much! Although, I dont think that the class needs to inherit from NSObject.

Comment: I think too but I translated line by line and in the objc interface there was the NSObject inheritance